# dereferencing 2D array using arithmetic

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, implicit-conversion, pointer-arithmetic

```
int main(void) 
{
    short arr[3][2]={3,5,11,14,17,20};
    printf("%d %d",*(arr+1)[1],**(arr+2));
    return 0;
}
```

Hi. In above code as per my understanding ,`*(arr+1)[1]` is equivalent to  `*(*(arr+sizeof(1D array)*1)+sizeof(short)*1)=>arr[1][1]`  i.e 14. But the program output is arr[2][0]. can someone please explain how dereferencing the array second time adds sizeof(1Darray)  i.e `*(*(arr+sizeof(1D array)*1)+sizeof(1D array)*1)=>arr[2][0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the C Standard (6.5.2.1 Array subscripting)

> 2 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets []
> is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The
> definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to
> (*((E1)+(E2))). Because of the conversion rules that apply to the
> binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer
> to the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer,
> E1[E2] designates the E2-th element of E1 (counting from zero).

So the expression

```
*(arr+1)[1]
```

can be rewritten like

```
* ( *( arr + 1 + 1 ) )
```

that is the same as

```
*( *( arr + 2 ) )
```

arr + 2 points to the third "row" of the array. Dereferencing the pointer expression you will get the "row" itself of the type `short[2]` that used in the expression `*( arr[2] )` is converted to pointer to its first element. So the expression equivalent to `arr[2][0]` yields the value 17.

Thus these two expressions

```
*(arr+1)[1],
```

and

```
**(arr+2)
```

are equivalent each other.

Note: pay attention to that there is a typo in your code

```
printf("%d %d",*(arr+1)[1],**(arr+2);
```

You need one more parenthesis

```
printf("%d %d",*(arr+1)[1],**(arr+2) );
```